# I can not get 'motion' working... seems to ignore changes to .conf file

Tags: permissions, users, webcam, devices

I am trying to use 'motion' to setup some simple video surveillance in Ubuntu 12.10.

I installed motion and edited the /etc/motion/motion.conf file, but it seems like the program is ignoring the changes I made to the .conf file.

First, I set the video device to /dev/video1 (a tested and working usb cam) 
but it is still using /dev/video0 (the built-in laptop cam)

Second, I set the camera resolution to 640x480
but it is capturing files that are 320x240

Third, I set the framerate to 2 frames/second
but it is recording about 10 frames/second

Forth, I set the target directory to a directory I created: 
/media/WORK DRIVE/motion capture/
but it is writing all the jpg files to the root directory instead.

I checked to make sure the user 'motion' was created and added to the group 'video' and it was.

What am I doing wrong?  I followed the instructions on the motion website as well as a few youtube tutorials... but it is still not working... it seems like all my changes to the motion.conf file are being ignored.

I am desperate... I need to get this up and running today.

Hope someone can help... thanks :-)

Comment: Anyone?  Is this a permissions issue? Do I need to set some kind of permissions for the user 'motion' other than what the program setup on installation?  Is this a naming convention problem with the target directory?  I have spaces in the directory name "/media/WORK DRIVE/motion capture/.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for one thing, if there is a file called motion.conf in your current directory (when you run the motion commmand) or there is a ~/.motion/motion.conf file, then motion will use those in preference to /etc/motion/motion.conf

worth checking those other files do not exist?